# Calendar button alignment issue in DateTimePicker in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using Both WPFToolkit and WPFExtendedtoolkit dll in our project to get `DateTimePicker`. But when the calendar pops down the Calendar button is not coming properly, half of the button are been hided.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for reply Jakub Kaleta, Here is the Screen shot

Comment: Since i am a new user,stack overflow asking me to earn 10 reputation to post image, Please let me know if their is any other way to post screen shot here

Comment: I think you will just have to wait until someone upvotes your question.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a late answer. But hope it helps others having same problem.
I think you have a style defined for Button in your custom styles.
Just add the following style to your custom styles.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```